# sed command to delete a line with contain more than 10 character which not start with 91

Tags: sed

I want sed command to delete a line from which which contain more than 10 number and which are not start with 91

My file content is like this

```
919876543210
789876543210
9012345678
12345678901
9865746321
```

And need output like this.

```
919876543210
9012345678
9865746321
```

I have tried awk 'length>=4' 1.txt | grep -v ^91

this will show me

```
789876543210
12345678901
```

Comment: If you do not show anything you have tried, StackOverflow system recommends downvoting your question and moving on.

Comment: Can `-E` be used with your version of sed?

Comment: sed version 4.2.2

Comment: That does not really answer the question, there are different sources of sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do:

- ignore all lines starting with "91", `/^91/!`
- otherwise delete anything with at least 11 characters
  (assuming you do not care about the difference between digits, letters, whitespace...),
  `{/.........../d}`

Altogether:

```
sed  '/^91/!{/.........../d}'
```

With the `-E` it would be more elegantly possible.

(My sed is GNU sed version 4.2.1)

Answer (score 1):

Simple, clear, portable, efficient, etc. with awk:

```
$ awk '/^91/ || length()<11' file
919876543210
9012345678
9865746321
```